Linux Mint 22 Cinnamon desktop not showing after installing iptables-persistent package (policy DROP)
I just installed Linux Mint 22 Cinnamon for the second time in one week, really frustrating. Reason being that after I have set up almost everything same as in Linux Mint 21.3 Cinnamon in a couple days without reboot, the desktop after reboot will just not show up, more exactly:

no background image, just black
only mouse cursor shown, and moving

This second time I am rebooting after every important system package installation to be able to spot the reason if it would happen again, and it just did. I installed the iptables-persistent package and edited the rules.v4 and rules.v6 to exactly as it's been in my previous Linux Mint 21.3 installation.
rules.v4
$ cat /etc/iptables/rules.v4

*filter

:INPUT      DROP      [0:0]
:FORWARD    DROP      [0:0]
:OUTPUT     ACCEPT    [0:0]

--append INPUT --in-interface lo --match comment --comment "Allow loopback" --jump ACCEPT

--append INPUT --match conntrack --ctstate INVALID --match comment --comment "Drop invalid packets" --jump DROP
--append INPUT --match conntrack --ctstate NEW --protocol tcp ! --syn --match comment --comment "Reject new non-syn TCP" --jump REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset

--append INPUT --protocol icmp --match limit --limit 100/second --limit-burst 500 --match comment --comment "Allow all ICMP with a limit" --jump ACCEPT

--append INPUT --match conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED --protocol tcp --match tcp --destination-port 22 --source 192.168.0.0/24 --match comment --comment "Allow local SSH on default port" --jump ACCEPT

--append INPUT --match conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED --match comment --comment "Traffic" --jump ACCEPT

COMMIT

rules.v6
$ cat /etc/iptables/rules.v6

*filter

:INPUT      DROP      [0:0]
:FORWARD    DROP      [0:0]
:OUTPUT     DROP      [0:0]

COMMIT


For some reason, the all-DROP policy in /etc/iptables/rules.v6 was the cause for this behavior.
I would really like to tell you why, but I don't know, maybe anyone else will, please post answer in such a case.
So, the solution, although my router is not connected to WAN6, is to set the policy to ACCEPT (INPUT + OUTPUT, FORWARD is irrelevant).
If your router is connected to WAN6 (IPv6), then be sure to set some set of rules though!
Hope this helps to anyone in the same situation.
